# How do we use Routine Group in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, diagram, mysql-workbench, routines

Since I can't find a way to add a routine to a diagram, I don't know how to use Routine Group tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Physical Schemdata" create/open a "routine group" and drag & drop your routines in the select box.

Click "Save" and your EER model should contains the routine group in the "catalog tree".

[link to mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-routine-groups.html)